# Operador postincremento y preincremento

Tags: java

Estoy el siguiente código:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10;) {
            i = i++;
            System.out.println("Hola Mundo");
            System.out.println("i = " + i); // Muestra i = 0
        }
```

No entiendo por qué `i` nunca es igual a `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preguntas como esta suelen salir en los exámenes de certificación de Java.

En [este enlace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) (en inglés) de la documentación de Oracle te explican qué está pasando en tu código. Teniendo en cuenta que increment operator es ++ y decrement operator es --, permitidme citar este trozo

> The increment/decrement operators can be applied before (prefix) or
> after (postfix) the operand. The code result++; and ++result; will
> both end in result being incremented by one. The only difference is
> that the prefix version (++result) evaluates to the incremented value,
> whereas the postfix version (result++) evaluates to the original
> value.

Que traducido vendría a ser

> Los operadores de incremento/decremento pueden aplicarse antes (prefijo) o después (posfijo) del operando. El código result++; y ++result; acabarán ambos con result siendo incrementado en uno. La única diferencia es que la versión prefijo (++result) se evalua al valor incrementado, mientras que la versión posfijo (result++) se evalua al valor original.

Aplicando esto a tu código

i = i++;

Teniendo en cuenta que i vale 0 inicialmente lo que hace es incrementarla en 1 pero como indica la documentación i++ se evalua al valor original 0 y es ese el valor que se acaba asignando quedando sin efecto el incremento.

Si cambias de sitio el operador sí verás que se va incrementando el valor de i

i = ++i;

Answer (score 5):

Te reproduzco la primera iteración paso a paso:

1.- `for (int i = 0; i < 10;) {`

En este punto se le asigna el valor `0` a `i`.

2.- `i = i++;`

En este punto `i` aumentaría su valor en `1` mediante el `i++`, pero como es un "postincremento" el valor que se asigna a `i` es el que tenía antes de incrementar, se incrementa el valor pero lo último que se ejecuta es la asignación, quedándose el valor de `i` como estaba.

Eso último no era necesario, podría haberse quedado como únicamente `i++`, sin la asignación.

3.- `System.out.println("Hola Mundo");`

Escribe "Hola Mundo".

4.- `System.out.println("i = " + i); // Muestra i = 0`

Aquí escribe "i = 0" porque `i` nunca se ha visto incrementado como esperabas.

---

Si quieres que empiece por `1` debes hacer correctamente el incremento de su valor:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10;) {
    i++;
    System.out.println("Hola Mundo");
    System.out.println("i = " + i); // Muestra i = 0
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Por generalizar, la operación:

```
variable = variable ++;
```

deja siempre el valor original. No sólo ocurre en Java, es algo que pasa también en los lenguajes en los que la operación *postincremento* existe, como C, C++, C# o Javascript:

```js
let i = 0
for (let j=0; j < 10; j++) {
   i=i++;
   console.log(i);
}
```

El motivo es la forma en la que la sentencia es interpretada/ejecutada: El postincremento a la variable se hace después de evaluar `i`, pero ANTES de la asignación:

1. Tenemos `i` a la izquierda
2. Tenemos `i` a la derecha, que se evalúa como `0`.
3. Una vez evaluado el valor que se va a guardar en `i` (la de la izquierda), se incrementa `i` en 1 (`i` vale momentáneamente 1)
4. Se asigna el valor evaluado en el paso 2 a `i`: `i = 0`

Comment: +1 Eso mismo estaba editando yo en mi respuesta x)

Answer (score 5):

La diferencia es que el postincremento retorna el valor anterior de la variable, el principal problema es que reasignas el valor del postincremento a la variable i, si cambias `i = i++;` por `i++;` o `i = ++i;` solucionaría el problema.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10;) {
   //     Soluciones 
        i++; // i = ++i;
        System.out.println("Hola Mundo");
        System.out.println("i = " + i); // Muestra i = 0
    }
```

Recuerda que la programación se ejecuta en general de derecha a izquierda, entonces tu logical para `i = i++` seria:

1. incremento 1 a i, i = 1
2. Como es postincremento retorno el valor anterior y lo asigna a i, i =0.
3. i que era 1 ahora vuelve al valor anterior 0 por la asignación.
4. El bucle queda infinito porque i nunca incrementa su valor.

Como puedes ver tu error es la asignación de `i = i++`, pero si la variable fuese otra funcionaria, `a` seria 0 y en la siguiente iteración 1 al igual que i incrementaría 1,2,3...10 y `a` tendría el valor anterior 0,1,2...9:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ) {
    int a = i++;
    System.out.println("Hola Mundo");
    System.out.println("a = " + a); 
    System.out.println("i = " + i);
}

Ejemplo de ejecución:
Hola Mundo
a = 0
i = 1
Hola Mundo
a = 1
i = 2
Hola Mundo
a = 2
i = 3
Hola Mundo
a = 3
i = 4
Hola Mundo
a = 4
i = 5
Hola Mundo
a = 5
i = 6
Hola Mundo
a = 6
i = 7
Hola Mundo
a = 7
i = 8
Hola Mundo
a = 8
i = 9
Hola Mundo
a = 9
i = 10
```